# Speeding up numerical Fourier Transform

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration, compile, fourier-analysis

I wrote this function `NFourierTransform`, which takes a function $f(k)$ and numerically calculates the fourier transform integral for discrete values of $k \in [k_{\text{min}},k_{\text{max}}]$, finally returning an `InterpolatingFunction` object.

```
NFourierTransform[f_Function, {kmin_, kmax_}] := 
 Interpolation@
  Table[{k, Chop@NIntegrate[f@x E^(-I k x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]},
   {k, kmin, kmax, (kmax - kmin)/100}]
```

In my application (calculating the time propagation of wave functions) I need to evaluate `NFourierTransform` for a function $\psi(k,t)$, where $t$ assumes discrete values in some interval $[t_{\text{min}},t_{\text{max}}]$. So effectively I create a table of `NFourierTransform`.

```
TimePropagate[f_Function, kl : {kmin_, kmax_}, {tl__}] :=
 Quiet@Table[
   NFourierTransform[f[#] Exp[-(#^2/2) t] &, kl], {t, tl}]
```

Calculating a very simple example with only 2 time values, e.g. `TimePropagate[Exp[-Abs@#] &, {-3, 3}, {0, 0.1, 0.1}]` takes about 20 seconds to evaluate.

Is there any way to use `Compile` to speed up the calculations? As far as I know that's only possible for numeric function arguments. What are, in your experience, suitable setings for `NIntegrate` options such as `MaxRecursion` or `AccuracyGoal`, and how do they effect evaluation time?

Comment: I never integrate over `t`. Each value for `t` is inserted, and the integration is over some variable `x`, where  `k` ranges from `kmin` to `kmax`.

Comment: I looked into that. My problem is that I don't really understand the mathematics behind discrete fourier transform (`Fourier`). I'm much more comfortable with continuous FT.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what can we assume of your function. If you can be sure about some bandwidth and support then using `Fourier` is surely a fast way. Meaning, a maximum frequency in which the function has a not too small fourier transform, and a maximum time in which the function is not too small.

Comment: If that's the case, I remembered a previous question in which [my poor answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1761/109) got the least votes and was barely seen. I don't even remember if it works but you could try it and let me know :P

Comment: That estimate function is a function of the frequency in Hz. To make that fit your fourier transform conventions you should evaluate it in `k/(2 Pi)` I think. Also, as is it assumes that your function is near 0 for negative arguments

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into your function. Might take me some time to fully understand what it does, though.

Comment: If your function `f` is slow to evaluate and you are evaluating it in the same places for each `t` in `tl`, you can implement `memoization` which means to cache the previous results. Look for that word in this site and you'll find lots of examples

Comment: One thing that comes to mind: you might want to explicitly set the `Method` option of `NIntegrate[]` to something that's equipped to handle oscillatory integrals, like `"DoubleExponentialOscillatory"` or `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"`.

Comment: What Rojo said. The responses [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/numerical-fourier-transform-of-a-complicated-function/1716#1716) seem to cover this topic. My answer got but one vote more than Rojo's. I think that fish might do what you want though (at least once suitably scaled).

Comment: Thanks. I still have some troubles understanding the mathematics behind deiscrete FT, but I'll definitely look into that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a play with various `Compile` options and didn't get anywhere (I managed to make it slower though!).  However, you can get a nice little speed boost using `ParallelTable`.  Your original on my machine:

```
NFourierTransform[f_Function, {kmin_, kmax_}] := 
 Interpolation@
  Table[{k, 
    Chop@NIntegrate[f@x E^(-I k x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]}, {k, 
    kmin, kmax, (kmax - kmin)/100}]
TimePropagate[f_Function, kl : {kmin_, kmax_}, {tl__}] := 
 Quiet@Table[NFourierTransform[f[#] Exp[-(#^2/2) t] &, kl], {t, tl}]
```

`TimePropagate[Exp[-Abs@#] &, {-3, 3}, {0, 0.1, 0.1}] // AbsoluteTiming` runs in 5.65 seconds.  I launch some kernels

```
LaunchKernels[]
```

and throw in a `ParallelTable`

```
NFourierTransform[f_Function, {kmin_, kmax_}] := 
 Interpolation@
  ParallelTable[{k, 
    Chop@NIntegrate[f@x E^(-I k x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]}, {k, 
    kmin, kmax, (kmax - kmin)/100}]
TimePropagate[f_Function, kl : {kmin_, kmax_}, {tl__}] := 
 Quiet@Table[NFourierTransform[f[#] Exp[-(#^2/2) t] &, kl], {t, tl}]
```

to get an execution time of 2.04 seconds for the same function call: `TimePropagate[Exp[-Abs@#] &, {-3, 3}, {0, 0.1, 0.1}] // AbsoluteTiming`

A speed-up of almost 3 times.

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to Mathematica at Stack Exchange! I've been reading your blog with great interest for a while now. It's great that you joined, and I hope you will like the community here. Gives me a pleasure to give you the first upvote on this site,+1.

Comment: Thanks.  I have been keeping an eye on this site for a while (I promoted the original proposal - http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4014 - hope it helped) and have learned many useful tricks here.  I rarely answer anything because the site regulars here are too efficient for their own good :)

Comment: Finally a useful tip that uses my original functions! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mike. I've edited your post to format it a little better. A tip: while backticks are useful for inline code, you can typeset blocks of code by indenting it by 4 spaces (or selecting it and pressing the `{}` button in the edit window). This way, it's also pretty printed with a custom _Mathematica_ syntax highlighter (developed here!)

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.  I did a very quick scan around the site to see how to do code formatting but didn't find anything.  Probably my bad as it was a VERY quck scan :)

Comment: Yeah, it can be a bit hard to find at times (they're linked to from the edit box, but I don't remember where), but for reference, here's the full list: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help :)